# Obtain nickname of telegram user

Tags: api, telegram

Is it possible to obtain the telegram user nickname using the Telegram client API if I don't have the contact in my rubric?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can get the User object. In the [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) Bot API documentation, there is a `from` field, which returns a [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object. In the User object, you will find all the user information that has sent the message to your bot.